# Cargar datos a partir de un select en otro con datos de MySQL PHP AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

No consigo que cargue los datos en el segundo `select`, la parte de `Ajax` no recibe los datos, pueden ayudarme?

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
          var fecha = $('fecha');
          var fecha_sel = $('fecha_sel');

          $('clase').change(function(){
                 var clase_id = $(this).val(); 
                   if(clase_id !== ''){ 
                      $.ajax({
                           data: {clase_id:nombre}, 
                           dataType: 'html',
                           type: 'POST', 
                           url: 'pantallaUser.php' 
                      }).done(function(data){          
                            fecha.html(data);            
                            fecha.prop('disabled', false); 
                      });

                    }else{ 
                           fecha.val(''); 
                           fecha.prop('disabled', true); 
                    }    
              });

             $('fecha_sel').html($(this).val() + ' - ' + 
             $('fecha option:selected').text());
             });
      });
    </script> 
    <?php   $id_clase= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clase_id'); 

     echo "id ".$id_clase;
     $SQLfecha = "select fecha from horarios where 
     id_clase = '".$id_clase."'";  
      $fechasObtenidas=ejecutar($SQLfecha);

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($id_clase)){
             $fecha= $row->fecha;
            echo "las fechas: ".$fechas;
?>  
 <option value="<?php echo $fecha;?>"><?php echo $fecha;?></option> <?php }?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de una aplicación antigua que tenia, como cargo los trabajadores y los buses según que empresa he seleccionado

```html
function cargarbustrabajador() {
    var em = document.getElementById("selectempresa");
    var empresa=em.options[em.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/rellenartrabajadores.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { empresa:empresa }
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#selecttrabajador').html(result);
        $('#selecttrabajador option[value=""]').html("Elige").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#selecttrabajador').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/rellenarbuses.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { empresa:empresa }
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#selectbus').html(result);
        $('#selectbus option[value=""]').html("Elige").attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
}
```

y el php

```html
<?php

require_once('../Conection.php');

$codigoempre=$_POST['empresa'];
$conection = Conection::getConection();
$acentos = mysqli_query($conection,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$bodyHtml='<option value=""></option>';
$query="SELECT Codigotrab, Nombre FROM trabajadores WHERE Codigoempre=$codigoempre AND Activo='Si' AND CodigoTrab>12";
   }
$result = mysqli_query($conection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $nombrecompleto = $row['Nombre'];
    list($apellidos, $nombre) = explode(", ", $nombrecompleto);
    $nombrelista = "$nombre $apellidos";
    $codigo=$row['Codigotrab'];
    $bodyHtml.="<option value='$codigo'>$nombrelista</option>";
}
echo $bodyHtml;
```

Hoy en día puedes cambiar la respuesta de "echo $bodyHtml"; por un JSON y el bucle te lo ahorras en el php y lo ejecutas en el JS recorriendo el JSON que te ha devuelto , espero te sirva si no tengo más ejemplos

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probaré.